# Filter DIV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a DIV like this

```
 <div *ngIf="viewModel != null" 
 id="filter_{{viewModel.countryId}}_{{viewModel.regionId}}" 
 class="filter_{{viewModel.countryId}}_{{viewModel.regionId}}">Some 
 text</div>
```

When I run, I will get the DIV like this

```
   <div id="filter_1_123" class="filter_1_123">Some text</div>
```

I have multiple DIVs like this

```
 <div id="filter_1_124" class="filter_1_124">Some text</div>

 <div id="filter_2_223" class="filter_2_223">Some text</div>

 <div id="filter_3_323" class="filter_3_323">Some text</div>
```

I want to filter div IDs starts with filter_1 (I am passing the 1 through the select option)

When I select 1 it has to show

```
 <div id="filter_1_123" class="filter_1_123">Some text</div>
 <div id="filter_1_124" class="filter_1_124">Some text</div>
```

All other DIVs should get hidden

Again through Select option I pass the value 123, at that time only

```
  <div id="filter_1_123" class="filter_1_123">Some text</div> should show and other DIV should get hidden.
```

Is there a way to do this through JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` with wildcard `div[id^='filter_1']` for filter div id start with `filter_1`

`var filter = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='filter_1']");`

```js
//var filter = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='filter_1']");
function filterValue(value){
var all = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='filter_']");

all.forEach(c=>c.removeAttribute("class","hide"));

var filter = document.querySelectorAll("div:not([id^='filter_" + value + "']");
filter.forEach(c=>c.setAttribute("class","hide"));
}
//console.log(filter.length);
//console.log(filter);
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="filterValue(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="filterValue(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="filterValue(3)">3</button>
<div id="filter_1_124" class="filter_1_124">Some text 1</div>

 <div id="filter_2_223" class="filter_2_223">Some text 2</div>

 <div id="filter_3_323" class="filter_3_323">Some text 3</div>
```

Comment: Initially all the DIV should display, when I select 1, then only the DIV id with filter_1 should display and other should get hidden.

Comment: Is there any way to make 'filter_1' dynamic value based on the selection I make. If I select 1 then it should filter_1, if I select 2 then it should filter_2

Comment: var filter = document.querySelectorAll("div:not([id^='filter_1'])"); This not working, it hides all the DIVs (that includes div id='filter_1_123' also)